# Docker Nodejs Multi Stage build Error. Dist not found

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-multi-stage-build

```
FROM node:14.9-stretch-slim AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
CMD ["yarn", "run", "build"]

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is my dockerfile. When I build it I get an error saying that dist not found.

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e397e0fd69733a25f53995c12dfbab7d24ce20867fede11886d49b9537976394/merged/usr/src/app/dist: no such file or directory
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is `CMD ["yarn", "run", "build"]` which should be RUN command like `RUN yarn run build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is using `CMD` instead of `RUN` at `CMD ["yarn", "run", "build"]`

```
FROM node:14.9-stretch-slim AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here are the docs for [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) and [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

From the docs about `CMD`:

> The main purpose of a `CMD` is to provide defaults for an executing container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit the executable, in which case you must specify an `ENTRYPOINT` instruction as well.

From the docs about `RUN`:

> The `RUN` instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

As you can see `CMD` is executed at runtime when running the container but `RUN` commands are used to build the docker image

#### How to debug this next time?

In your Dockerfile you can basically run any executable part of the image. So to check if the dist folder exists or what are the contents of it you could just use `ls`

```
FROM node:14.9-stretch-slim AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build
RUN ls -la dist 

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly. That was a really silly mistake. I totally missed that.